# Как скомпилить "Hello world" в С++ Qt в Linux?

Tags: qt, c++

Самый простой пример:

```
#include <QApplication>  
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    QApplication a(argc, argv);  
    Qlabel  label;  
    label.setText("Hello World");  
    label.show();  
    a.exec();  
}
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
test.cpp:1:51: fatal error: QApplication: No such file or directory
 #include <QApplication>
```

Не помогает:

```
#include <"/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/QApplication.h">  
#include <"/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/QLabel.h">
```

та же ошибка.

Все библиотеки у меня установлены.

Comment: что в файле .pro?

Comment:     #include <QtGui/QApplication>
попробуйте так

Comment: вы использовали Qt Creator?

Comment: у вас не привязан или плохо привязан компилятор в Qt Creator

Comment: смотрите настройки Qt Creator

Comment: А вы записали именно `#include <"/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/QApplication.h">`? Т.е. у вас и угловые скобки, и кавычки? И что будет, если запустить g++, подсунув ему в явном виде пути до хедеров (ключ -I /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/)?

Также вопрос, почему в QTCreator кнопка не активна, что там в параметрах - сборка и запуск?

Comment: при том что если разобраться почему не пашет креатор возможно станет понятно почему и g++ не работает. У вас хоть файлы-то в /usr/include/qt есть?

Comment: возможно, ошибка вылетает из-за того, что вы подключили QLabel после QApplication

Comment: и как это вы label используете без QMainWindow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нет желания делать это в QtCreator (например, слабая машина, 16мб памяти, первый пентиум) или ярый приверженец консоли, то можно все сделать.

Первое - нужно исправить ошибку в сорцах. `Qlabel` написан с маленькой `l`, должна быть заглавная.

После этого открываем консоль, переходим в каталог с сорцом и вводим команду `qmake-qt4 -project` (это так в федоре, в других системах бывают отличия, я видел `qmake4` и просто `qmake`). Эта команда сгенерирует файл проекта где-то такого вида:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET =
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
SOURCES += examle.cpp
```

Этот файл можно открыть QtCreator'ом, но мы легких путей не ищем.

Следующим шагом нужно запустить ту же команду `qmake-qt4`, но уже без параметров. Она на основе pro файла сгенерирует обычный Makefile. Теперь можно спокойно компилировать обычной командой make.

Поизучав Makefile изнутри, можно разобраться, как все-таки компилировать ручкам с консоли напрямую, но кол-во символов, которые нужно будет ввести, будет немаленькое. Так что лучше Makefile.

> и как это вы label используете без QMainWindow?

Так можно. QLabel может быть окном.